# Upgrade React-App to use JSX transform - breaks the app (Propery 'React' doesn't exist)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I do have an react-native project.
I've upgraded to recent react and react-native version, even as all other packages in the project.
As React 17 brings the JSX-Transform (https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#manual-babel-setup) I followed those steps to use it in my app.

But at least it doesn't work as expected.

I wonder if the new JSX-Transform feature doesn't be usable for react-native APP's, but only for general react webprojects?!

This is my babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
      {
        legacy: true,
      },
    ],
    [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
      {
        runtime: 'automatic',
      },
    ],
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

this my eslintrc.json:

```
{
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "react-native/react-native": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "@react-native-community",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb-base",
    "prettier/react"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-native",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "object-curly-newline": 0,
    "max-len": [
      "error",
      {
        "code": 100,
        "comments": 150,
        "ignoreTrailingComments": true,
        "ignoreUrls": true
      }
    ],
    "indent": [
      "warn",
      2
    ],
    "linebreak-style": [
      "error",
      "unix"
    ],
    "quotes": [
      2,
      "single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true,
        "allowTemplateLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    "semi": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    "react-native/no-unused-styles": 2,
    "react-native/split-platform-components": 2,
    "react-native/no-inline-styles": 2,
    "react-native/no-color-literals": 2,
    "react-native/no-raw-text": 2,
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "warn",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto",
        "bracketSpacing": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution to make it work with react native

https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/646#issuecomment-799174473

So by using both useTransformReactJSXExperimental and runtime settings in babel configuration file.

Comment: That solution with `useTransformReactJSXExperimental: true` is only for older react versions like 0.64.x. I've tried this before.